# Why does a table have larger borders in IE than FireFox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table that displays pictures in each td element. The page is essentially a gallery.

In Firefox, there is a SMALL(5px) margin (or padding?) around each picture inside the td element. No matter how many pictures in the table the margin never changes. **All that is great & what I want.**

In IE, there is a LARGE(40px) margin (or padding?) around each picture inside the td element. When there are more pictures in the table the margin/padding is greater. **This is not what I want**

In both scenarios, each picture is the same size about (100px by 100px) which is what I want.

How can I make sure that IE does not have these weird margins around each picture? And just maintain the constant 5px margin around each picture?

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Kaz Early Learning Centre - Local Childcare - Dolans Bay NSW</title>

    <style type="text/css" media="all">

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="gallery" align="center">

        <table align="center">

            <tr> </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td>
                    <a href="/cgi-bin/showPicture.py?picPath=images/gallery/Open Day 2010/IMG_0215_resized.JPG">
                        <img src="images/gallery/Open Day 2010/IMG_0215_resized.JPG" class="pic" style="max-width: 100px; width: expression(this.width > 100 ? 100: true); max-height: 200px; height: expression(this.height > 200 ? 200: true);" />
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/cgi-bin/showPicture.py?picPath=images/gallery/Open Day 2010/IMG_2262_resized.JPG">
                        <img src="images/gallery/Open Day 2010/IMG_2262_resized.JPG" class="pic" style="max-width: 100px; width: expression(this.width > 100 ? 100: true); max-height: 200px; height: expression(this.height > 200 ? 200: true);" />
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/cgi-bin/showPicture.py?picPath=images/gallery/Open Day 2010/IMG_0223_resized.JPG">
                        <img src="images/gallery/Open Day 2010/IMG_0223_resized.JPG" class="pic" style="max-width: 100px; width: expression(this.width > 100 ? 100: true); max-height: 200px; height: expression(this.height > 200 ? 200: true);" />
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td>
                    <a href="/cgi-bin/showPicture.py?picPath=images/gallery/Open Day 2010/IMG_0196_resized.JPG">
                        <img src="images/gallery/Open Day 2010/IMG_0196_resized.JPG" class="pic" style="max-width: 100px; width: expression(this.width > 100 ? 100: true); max-height: 200px; height: expression(this.height > 200 ? 200: true);" />
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/cgi-bin/showPicture.py?picPath=images/gallery/Open Day 2010/IMG_0223_resized.JPG">
                        <img src="images/gallery/Open Day 2010/IMG_0223_resized.JPG" class="pic" style="max-width: 100px; width: expression(this.width > 100 ? 100: true); max-height: 200px; height: expression(this.height > 200 ? 200: true);" />
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/cgi-bin/showPicture.py?picPath=images/gallery/Open Day 2010/IMG_0220_resized.JPG">
                        <img src="images/gallery/Open Day 2010/IMG_0220_resized.JPG" class="pic" style="max-width: 100px; width: expression(this.width > 100 ? 100: true); max-height: 200px; height: expression(this.height > 200 ? 200: true);" />
                    </a>

                </td>
            </tr> 

            <tr> 
                <td>
                    <a href="/cgi-bin/showPicture.py?picPath=images/gallery/Open Day 2010/IMG_0196_resized.JPG">
                        <img src="images/gallery/Open Day 2010/IMG_0196_resized.JPG" class="pic" style="max-width: 100px; width: expression(this.width > 100 ? 100: true); max-height: 200px; height: expression(this.height > 200 ? 200: true);" />
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/cgi-bin/showPicture.py?picPath=images/gallery/Open Day 2010/IMG_0223_resized.JPG">
                        <img src="images/gallery/Open Day 2010/IMG_0223_resized.JPG" class="pic" style="max-width: 100px; width: expression(this.width > 100 ? 100: true); max-height: 200px; height: expression(this.height > 200 ? 200: true);" />
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/cgi-bin/showPicture.py?picPath=images/gallery/Open Day 2010/IMG_0220_resized.JPG">
                        <img src="images/gallery/Open Day 2010/IMG_0220_resized.JPG" class="pic" style="max-width: 100px; width: expression(this.width > 100 ? 100: true); max-height: 200px; height: expression(this.height > 200 ? 200: true);" />
                    </a>

                </td>
            </tr> 

            <tr> 
                <td>
                    <a href="/cgi-bin/showPicture.py?picPath=images/gallery/Open Day 2010/IMG_0196_resized.JPG">
                        <img src="images/gallery/Open Day 2010/IMG_0196_resized.JPG" class="pic" style="max-width: 100px; width: expression(this.width > 100 ? 100: true); max-height: 200px; height: expression(this.height > 200 ? 200: true);" />
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/cgi-bin/showPicture.py?picPath=images/gallery/Open Day 2010/IMG_0223_resized.JPG">
                        <img src="images/gallery/Open Day 2010/IMG_0223_resized.JPG" class="pic" style="max-width: 100px; width: expression(this.width > 100 ? 100: true); max-height: 200px; height: expression(this.height > 200 ? 200: true);" />
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/cgi-bin/showPicture.py?picPath=images/gallery/Open Day 2010/IMG_0220_resized.JPG">
                        <img src="images/gallery/Open Day 2010/IMG_0220_resized.JPG" class="pic" style="max-width: 100px; width: expression(this.width > 100 ? 100: true); max-height: 200px; height: expression(this.height > 200 ? 200: true);" />
                    </a>

                </td>
            </tr> 

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="/cgi-bin/showPicture.py?picPath=images/gallery/Open Day 2010/IMG_0220_resized.JPG">
                        <img src="images/gallery/Open Day 2010/IMG_0220_resized.JPG" class="pic" style="max-width: 100px; width: expression(this.width > 100 ? 100: true); max-height: 200px; height: expression(this.height > 200 ? 200: true);" />
                    </a>
                </td>   
                <td>
                    <a href="/cgi-bin/showPicture.py?picPath=images/gallery/Open Day 2010/IMG_0196_resized.JPG">
                        <img src="images/gallery/Open Day 2010/IMG_0196_resized.JPG" class="pic" style="max-width: 100px; width: expression(this.width > 100 ? 100: true); max-height: 200px; height: expression(this.height > 200 ? 200: true);" />
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try getting rid of the expressions if you're viewing in ie 7+ [this](http://tekkie.flashbit.net/browsers/internet-explorer-dumping-css-hacks-to-comply-with-standards) explains that they got rid of expression support in favor of actually fixing their crappy css handling

Comment: but then how do I resize my images? so they aren't huge for some & others small?

Comment: by using `max-width` which has been supported since IE7. Use percentages if you want the widths to be relative to their containers.

Comment: thanks this is my solution, if the user is on IE I resize by percentage, if on anything else I use the expressions. Seems to work on all browsers but I am unsure of it works on previous versions of IE & firefox. I use python to determine the users browser platform

Comment: All of the other browsers work as expected, I would just get rid of the expressions all together, they are only relevant for ie6 and earlier. Firefox, and all of the other browsers worth noting work as expected with `max-height` and `max-width`

Answer (score 3):

Different browsers use different defaults for the settings although I wouldn't have expected it to be that different.  You could try using a global reset file for your CSS settings.  You can find examples [here](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=css%20reset).

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers have different defaults for these things.  If you want to control padding, borders, etc, either specify them in the [table definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html), or use [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/)

---

```
<style>
   .my_table {
       padding: 0px;
       margin: 0px;
       border: 0px;
   }
</style>
<table class="my_table">
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I already knew that, I'm kindof asking for a CSS example etc. to show how to avoid this problem

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things going on in your code:

1. You should probably use a CSS reset like this one: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/ . This will reset all browsers to use the same CSS settings fox box model (padding/margin/etc) to a standard value. Each browser can default these differently - even between versions of browser.
2. Why are you using CSS expressions and in-line CSS? You could achieve the same with Javascript and it's more cross-browser compliant. Your inline CSS will also be difficult to override since it's in the style attribute of the tag.

   - #1 should solve your problem. #2 is just best practices.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use normalize.css. It works like a reset css.

You can find it here: http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what is happening without seeing your CSS.

However, if you want to control the padding/margins for your table, you should first reset everything in the table.

So, give the table an ID or class name `<table class="imagesTable">`

Then reset the CSS as follows in your stylesheet:

```
table.imagesTable tr td, table.imagesTable tr td a, table.imagesTable tr td a img  {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
}
```

This targets the all three elements in the table cell.  You may also want to reset the `tr`s, but that is probably not necessary.

You may need to add `!important` to your style rule in order to override some other styles that might be applied.

Once done, you can add back some nice padding to the `td`

```
table.imagesTable tr td {
    padding:5px;
}
```